# unresolved inclusion error eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, inclusion

So I went to this thing call the digital media academy for 3D game programming. We used eclipse along with Panda3D using their Macbook Pro's to create 3D games. I created an awesome game there which ran beautifully. However when I put everything on a USB and installed everything back on my personal macbook pro at home, I see question marks next to these lines of code that say Unresolved inclusion:

// Panda3D stuff.

```
#include "auto_bind.h"
#include "audioManager.h"
#include "executionEnvironment.h"
#include "filename.h"
```

//C++ stuff

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
```

In the problems section of eclipse I get this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, there are at least two issues here.:

1. Unresolved includes: 
    This can be a glitch with the indexer, a simple index rebuild or a recompile would help
    Try Right click on project > Index > "Rebuild" or "Re-resolve Unresolved Includes"
    If no luck then,it's not just a glich but a real problem, so check:
    Project > Properties > C/C++ General > Path and Symbols > Includes
    There you should have the directories where the C++ headers are and 
    the "Panda" headers should be with your source files.
2. Missing "all" target:
    What CDT is trying to do is invoking make with a target called "all" which is missing 
    from your Makefile. Either CDT is configured for the wrong target and 
    the "all" is not what you need, or something is wrong with the "all" target. 
    You should provide us more information: the proper (original) Makefile
    The settings here: Project > Properties > C/C++ Build > Behaviour > Make build target